# Optimize Implementation - Wait for all threads using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, multithreading

In my program I read several information's about the system. I read each categories like CPU, memory, services, software and so on with a own thread. The main program have to wait for the longest thread.

To implement this, I use `LINQ` and the `Join` function from `Thread`.

Here is a small part from my code:

```
var culture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US");
var thread_list = new List<Thread>();
var c = new Computer();

var thrma = new Thread(() =>
{
    c.Mainboard = new Mainboard().GetInformation();
});
thrma.CurrentUICulture = culture;
thrma.Start();
thread_list.Add(thrma);

var thrce = new Thread(() =>
{
    c.ProcessorList = new CentralProcessingUnit().GetInformation();
});
thrce.CurrentUICulture = culture;
thrce.Start();
thread_list.Add(thrce);

...

var thrsvr = new Thread(() =>
{
    DeviceService.ScanServices();
});
thrsvr.CurrentUICulture = culture;
thrsvr.Start();
thread_list.Add(thrsvr);

foreach (Thread t in thread_list)
{
    t.Join();
}

// Everyone is done!
```

Each hardware device is derived from the Hardware class.

What do you think about the solution? Is there a "nicer" or better implementation? I would like to use a function, because the code is very similar, but I'm not sure how to do it. Any idea?

Thanks for your advices.

Comment: Which .NET version are you using? Are these `Mainboard`, `CentralProcessingUnit` and `DeviceService` classes written by you or came from 3rd-party library?

Comment: I use .Net 4. I wrote those classes.

Comment: I have forgotten to say, that the threads are running in a services.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's better to use new asynchronous API since it provides more features for combining asynchronous tasks.

Ideally `Mainboard`, `CentralProcessingUnit` and `DeviceService` should expose asynchronous API if a certain operation is not trivial, so (as you mentioned in comments you wrote them) I would implement asynchronous API for them first, e.g.:

```
public class Mainboard
{
    public Task<string> GetInformationAsync()
    {
        //TODO: extract long-term operation into Task. Try not to span extra threads here
    }
}
```

Then your method would look like:

```
Task.WaitAll(
    new Mainboard().GetInformationAsync().ContinueWith(task => c.Mainboard = task.Result),
    new CentralProcessingUnit().GetInformationAsync().ContinueWith(task => c.ProcessorList = task.Result),
    DeviceService.ScanServicesAsync());
```

If you decide not to implement async API the code can look like:

```
var c = new Computer();

Task.WaitAll(
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => c.Mainboard = new Mainboard().GetInformation()),
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => c.ProcessorList = new CentralProcessingUnit().GetInformation()),
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => DeviceService.ScanServices()));
```

Comment: Looks very nice! Is it possible to set the `CultureInfo` in the `Task`. The asynchronous API doesn't block the main program, right? Thanks!

Comment: I would rather explicitly pass `CultureInfo` to methods that require it instead of relying on current thread CultureInfo.